# How is the parameter involved in order to let function one "know" that it shall react to what happens in function two?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

The following code actually works, but I don't understand why. How come that when I pass the "event"-parameter to the function zaehle(), the function actually "knows" that it is supposed to react on what happens in the setup function?

I just can't see what connnects the zaehle() and the setup() function or how the parameter that I pass to zaehle() would be involved.

I hope I could make the question clear. If not I'll gladly try to explain it somehow else. It really bugs me and I feel like I can't go on studying until I get it.

```
<body>

<div id="eins">0</div>
<div id="zwei">0</div>
<div id="drei">0</div>
<div id="vier">0</div>
<div id="funf">0</div>

</body>
```

JS

```
var mouseoverZaehler = 0;

function zaehle(event) {
    mouseoverZaehler++;
    event.target.innerHTML = mouseoverZaehler;
}

function setup() {
    document.getElementById("eins").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
    document.getElementById("zwei").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
    document.getElementById("drei").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
    document.getElementById("vier").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
    document.getElementById("funf").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
```

Comment: The *browser* passes the event parameter to the event handler. It's just how browsers work. (Old versions of Internet Explorer did *not* do that however.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addEventListener` calls in your `setup` function tell the browser that when a `mouseover` event occurs on the relevant element, it should call the function you're giving it (`zaehle`, in your case). It's the *browser* that passes the argument to `zaehle`, later, when calling it.

You could imagine `addEventListener`, *conceptually*, as putting that handler function on a list for the event on the element:

```
// VERY conceptual, leaves out a lot of details
function addEventListener(eventName, handler) {
    this.events[eventName].handlers.push(handler);
}
```

...and then later, when the event occurs, the browser creates an event object and calls those handlers:

```
// Again, VERY conceptual, leaves out a lot of details
var event = /*...*/;
element.events[eventName].handlers.forEach(function(handler) {
    handler.call(element, event);
});
```

Here's a working analogue of what's going on:

```js
function FakeElement () {
    this.events = Object.create(null);
}
FakeElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, handler) {
    var eventEntry = this.events[eventName];
    if (!eventEntry) {
        eventEntry = this.events[eventName] = {
            handlers: []
        };
    }
    eventEntry.handlers.push(handler);
};
FakeElement.prototype.trigger = function(eventName) {
    var event = {type: eventName};                    // "Browser" creates the event
    var eventEntry = this.events[eventName];
    var handlers = eventEntry && eventEntry.handlers;
    if (handlers) {
        handlers.forEach(function(handler) {
            handler.call(this, event);                // "Browser" calls handler, passing
        });                                           // the event into it
    }
};

// Using it:
function zaehle(event) {
  console.log("zaehle got event: " + event.type);
}

var e = new FakeElement();
e.addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle);
console.log("added handler for mouseover to element");

// Simulate the event occurring
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  e.trigger("mouseover");
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens step by step:

1. Page loads
2. `setup` function is called (because of `window.addEventListener("load", setup)`)
3. Each element in setup function gets a mouseover event listener attached to it and when it fires `zaehle` function is called (because of `document.getElementById("number").addEventListener("mouseover", zaehle)`)
4. You move your mouse over any of the elements
5. `zaehle` function gets called - `mouseoverZaehler` is incremented and `innerHTML` of the targeted element is set to the updated value of `mouseoverZaehler`

Check out [addEventListener docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You have registered your callback/function `zaehle()` for `mouseover` event. So when that event occurs for a specific div, browser calls the callback with `event` object which contains information about the event and the target i.e event occurred on which element.